# simple coding for yii form with redbeanphp

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am new to yii framework and redbeanphp. I want to start a new website application using yii framework and redbeanphp.

How to sample user input form using yii framework and update, insert, delete using redbeanphp coding?

Comment: I like both redbean and yii, but why use them together?  Yii has a great active record.  Using redbean will make you rewrite almost the entire model if you want to incorporate it completely.

Answer (score 1):

Redbeanphp is a great tool for db structuring and initialization,great to use with frameworks which do not manage db or with your own simple framework.

Considering using Yii with php Redbeanphp , yii already manages the db very well , infact if you use redbeanphp, you will have following disadvantages

- You will not be able to use Yii Migrations ([read more here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration))
- Yii active record is better to work with if you are developing with yii rather than redbeanphp based schema manipulation.
- Yii built in relation mapping and data access has more functionality  (slightly more difficult to comprehend at first though)

You will give up all this for one extra advantage I see which is not part of Yii : No need to setup any configuration. It does save 5 minutes when you start making an app but certainly not worth it for me.

For you, I recommend you also explore yii migrations more and find out that what redbeanphp offers is part of yii already in one way or another.

You don't need to dump redbeanphp, you can still use it for apps where u don't want to use yii, or with frameworks who don't manage db very well or if u r making your own framework by integrating other frameworks.